# Is there an expression equivalent to not assigning a property in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I have the following (bloated, but working) code:

```js
const foo: { [key: string]: string } = {}
if (bar != null) {
  foo.bar = bar
}
```

This seems like it could be simplified. I tried this, thinking that `undefined` meant that the property was really "not defined":

```js
const foo: { [key: string]: string } = {
  bar: bar ?? undefined
}
```

Unfortunately, I was met with the compilation error "`string | undefined` is not assignable to type `string`".

I had heard of `never` so I tried this too:

```js
const foo: { [key: string]: string } = {
  bar: bar ?? never
}
```

This time I get the error "`never` only refers to a type, but is used as a value here".

Is there really no expression equivalent to not having ever assigned the property in the first place? What's the purpose of `undefined` or `never` if they don't really mean that the property doesn't exist.

(I can't change foo's type to allow null or undefined)

Comment: There is a difference in having a property and it being `undefined` or `null` and not having the property, so I do not believe any of your attempts preserve that distinction by always having a `bar` property. This distinction may not matter to you, but it is a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to assign a property conditionally you can use this:

```
const foo: { [key: string]: string } = {
  ...(bar && { bar })
}
```

If `bar` is `undefined` `foo` will be an empty object. **But be aware:** If bar is `0` the property will also **not** get assigned. If this is not what you want use this:

```
const foo: { [key: string]: string } = {
  ...(bar !== undefined && { bar })
}
```